# InvalidAuthenticationToken - MS Graph - One Drive Token

Tags: c#, graph, token

I am trying to use the access token received from *Microsoft* online for *OneDrive* upload.

I get token at :https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

Token is not valid and redirect url is not localhost.

When trying to use it; I get an error:

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: InvalidAuthenticationToken

I tried to copy it to https://jwt.ms/ and it seems the token is invalid.

Access Token is similar to this:

```
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
```

Comment: Did you check that the token is not expired? Along with the token, you get the time can be active/alive.

Comment: Yes. It is valid one hour. So I authenticate, get authorization code then request token and the token is valid for one hour but it seems it is invalid